# Do I have two versions of Libre Office?

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, libreoffice

**Update**: thanks, @karel. Your 'update-alternatives' command showed no alternatives. I can proceed from here.

**OP**:
I'm using 16.04.

The appearance and behavior of LO changed for me a little while ago. I can get my work done, but I wondered what's going on. I think I remember that the 'Ubuntu Software' version is v 5, but I also think I tried v6 at one point.

When I bring up an OD file or open LO Calc directly, I see a reference to version 5. This also appears in Help/About.

But dpkg -l | grep shows references to 6.2.7.1

- Do I have 2 versions installed?
- Can I uninstall only one of them?
- Can I choose which one the launchbar icon calls?

[image: help about]

[image: dpkg]

Comment: If you've installed snaps, they don't who up in `dpkg` or `apt` searches (unless the snap was installed by a deb).  Use `snap list` to view any snap applications you may have installed (LibreOffice is available as snap too)

Comment: Thanks, @guiverc. Command 'snap list' returns "No snaps are installed yet...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LibreOffice version 5.1.6.2 is the current version of the default LibreOffice package in Ubuntu 16.04 the same version as shown in *Help* -> *About*, so it is clear that you have the default LibreOffice apt package installed. The results of `dpkg -l | grep libreoffice` show that you have two different versions of LibreOffice Writer, Calc and Math installed alongside each other and both LibreOffice versions were installed by apt.

To select one version of LibreOffice as the default version run the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config libreoffice
```

If the results of the above command are `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for libreoffice` then there is only one version of LibreOffice currently installed. Otherwise it will show both versions of LibreOffice with a selection number in front of each one and the following message:

```
Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Enter the selection number and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select it. Then confirm that the selected version of LibreOffice is now the default version by opening LibreOffice and selecting *Help* -> *About*.

To uninstall one version of LibreOffice install Synaptic Package Manager (`sudo apt install synaptic`). Open synaptic with `pkexec synaptic`, select *Status* -> *Installed*, search for *libreoffice*, and remove all the packages for the LibreOffice version that you want to uninstall. Right-click on each package that you want to remove and from the pop-up context menu select *Mark for Removal*. Then click the *Apply* gear icon in the toolbar to apply the changes.